# How can I add a new grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

How can I add another variable as a grouping variable based on the date? Here is my data:

```
df <- tibble(id = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 3)),
             col = structure(c(19031, 19031, 19031, 19031, 19072, 19072, 19072, 19072, 19031, 19031, 
                               19031), class = "Date"),
             grouping_var = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,4), rep(1, 3) ) )
```

and the column `grouping_variable` is the expected outcome I want to have. So  Basically, I want to assign a grouping based on the date.  If an `id` has more than one date in the `col` then the first date gets assigned a `1` and the second a `2`, and if an id has only one date the it only gets a `1`. A dpylr solution would be particularly great here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can group by `id`, then `match` the dates column against the sorted `unique` values of itself.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(grouping_var = match(col, sort(unique(col))))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>       id col        grouping_var
#>    <dbl> <date>            <int>
#>  1     1 2022-02-08            1
#>  2     1 2022-02-08            1
#>  3     1 2022-02-08            1
#>  4     1 2022-02-08            1
#>  5     1 2022-03-21            2
#>  6     1 2022-03-21            2
#>  7     1 2022-03-21            2
#>  8     1 2022-03-21            2
#>  9     2 2022-02-08            1
#> 10     2 2022-02-08            1
#> 11     2 2022-02-08            1
```

Comment: Maybe change `unique(col)` to `sort(unique(col))` in case dates are not sorted in df.

Comment: As `match` is now having a sorted vector maybe the usage of `findInterval` instead of `match` can be more efficient (binary against linear search). `match(col, sort(unique(col)))` to `findInterval(col, sort(unique(col)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum(duplicated(.))` in `ave`.

```
transform(df, grouping_var2=ave(as.numeric(col), id, 
                                FUN=\(x) cumsum(!duplicated(sort(x)))[order(x)]))
#    id        col grouping_var
# 1   1 2022-02-08            1
# 2   1 2022-02-08            1
# 3   1 2022-02-08            1
# 4   1 2022-02-08            1
# 5   1 2022-03-21            2
# 6   1 2022-03-21            2
# 7   1 2022-03-21            2
# 8   1 2022-03-21            2
# 9   2 2022-02-08            1
# 10  2 2022-02-08            1
# 11  2 2022-02-08            1
```

Alternatively using `findInterval` as `@GKi` suggests:

```
transform(df, grouping_var2=ave(as.numeric(col), id, 
                                FUN=\(x) findInterval(x, sort(unique(x)))))
```

For `dplyr` just use `mutate` instead of `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank()` in `dplyr`, which is a wrapper of `match(x, sort(unique(x)))`.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(grp_var = dense_rank(col))

# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id col        grouping_var
   <dbl> <date>            <int>
 1     1 2022-02-08            1
 2     1 2022-02-08            1
 3     1 2022-02-08            1
 4     1 2022-02-08            1
 5     1 2022-03-21            2
 6     1 2022-03-21            2
 7     1 2022-03-21            2
 8     1 2022-03-21            2
 9     2 2022-02-08            1
10     2 2022-02-08            1
11     2 2022-02-08            1
```